# How far could I travel in distance if I jumped off the ISS outward into space?

Tags: space, distance

How far would I travel if I were on the ISS and jumped outwardly into open space?

Answer (score 3):

The thing to be aware of is that orbital motion is a trajectory that loops back onto itself.

The ISS goes around the Earth in about 90 minutes. That is: every 90 minutes the ISS is back where it was 90 minutes before.

For simplicity let's assume the orbit of the ISS is perfectly circular.

If you would jump away from the ISS:
You would still be orbiting the Earth, but in an orbit that is slightly non-circular. The period of your orbit would still be 90 minutes.

(The amount of velocity difference that you can achieve with a jump is negligable compared to the orbital velocity.)

After 90 minutes the orbital motion brings you back to the ISS. Your (slightly non-circular) orbit will make you pass close to the ISS every 90 minutes

Comment: This is a fairly good answer, though I'd add that if you add or subtract orbital velocity in the direction of motion the semi-major axis and therefore orbital period will change. Therefore, close approaches between the jumper and space station will drift further apart each orbit. Even for initial velocities of several m/s there may be 10s of km drift each orbit.

Comment: @FTT You are correct, of course. I only considered the case of a jump at right angles to the instantaneous direction of orbital motion. (The question uses the wording: "jump outwardly")

Comment: @FTT More generally: for a first approximation it is generally considered acceptable to omit things that if included would give a correction less than 10%. When writing an answer there is a judgement call: I follow a policy of measuring the level of approximation in the answer to line up with the question. In this particular case I opted to provide the first approximation only. Here the first approximation is *sufficient*; it provides the key information. Proceeding to closer approximation would make the answer less focused.